# Matlab : Remove skin part on segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to remove skin parts on segmentation ?

First, I made this first picture smaller, since the picture is somehow intimidating, I'll give the image at the end section.

[image]

I'm using RGB & ycbcr segmentation, but it seems the segmentation didn't work well.

```
clear all;
  close all;
  clc;

   img=imread('acne.jpg');


 %ycbcr segmentation
   img_ycbcr=img;  %image from the previous segmentation
   ycbcr=rgb2ycbcr(img_ycbcr);
   cb=ycbcr(:,:,2);
   cr=ycbcr(:,:,3);


    %Detect Skin
    %[r,c,v] = find(cb>=77 & cb<=127 & cr>=133 & cr<=173);
     [r c v] = find(cb<=77 | cb >=127 | cr<=133 | cr>=173);
    numid = size(r,1);

    %Mark Skin Pixels
    for i=1:numid
        img_ycbcr(r(i),c(i),:) = 0;
       % bin(r(i),c(i)) = 1;
    end

    figure
    title('ycbcr segmentation');
   imshow(img_ycbcr);

 %==============================================================
  %rgb segmentation

img_rgb=img_ycbcr;
r=img_rgb(:,:,1);
g=img_rgb(:,:,2);
b=img_rgb(:,:,3);


[row col v]= find(b>0.79*g-67 & b<0.78*g+42 & b>0.836*g-14 & b<0.836*g+44 ); %non skin pixels
numid=size(row,1);

for i=1:numid
    img_rgb(row(i),col(i),:)=0;
end


figure
imshow(img_rgb);
```

[image]

Here my sample :

[image]

Comment: Pure colourwise this is a nightmare, as both the acne and the bright skin on the top of the picture are white, almost the same colour. I suspect doing this with only colour separation will be difficult, you'd need to check for e.g. the surroundings: is the white area approximately white, is it surrounded by a red ring etc

Comment: Hi thanks I'm looking for alternative for color based.

Comment: Yeah, try some edge detection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Adriaan. Don't do it with just colour, use additional information such as the shape and the edges.

The last two colorplanes seem to have the most contrast, so let's use one of them:

```
Nipple = imread('N8y6Q.jpg')

Nipple = imadjust(Nipple(:,:,2));

imshow(Nipple)
```

[image: grayscale of the green plane of the image]

```
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Nipple, [30,60]);

hold on

imshow(Nipple);
viscircles(centers, radii);
```

[image: grayscale with segmented area]

The circular Hough transform is a robust way to find circular objects if you know the approximate radius range and are satisfied with the approx. location and size of the object.

If not you can try other classical methods, e.g. (Canny) edge detection, using the Hough center point as a marker -> region growing, fitting a snake etc. etc.

Comment: Just a small remark: it's acne, not a nipple. Otherwise you might want to visit a doctor...

Comment: I noticed. I like to wing it with my variable names, silly stuff is easier to remember. And it becomes a habit even when not relevant. Yeah giving away code can be awkward..